# how to declare a global variable assign value in one function and use in another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I just write a test html file to learn about object in javascript. The code is as follows

in script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var obj = new ParentFn();
    var obj2 = new AnotherParentFn();
    var temp;
    function initer()
    {
        temp = obj.Adding();
        obj2.caller();
    }
    function ParentFn()
    {
        this.a = 10;
        this.b = 20;
    }
    function AnotherParentFn()
    {
        this.a = 30;
        this.b = 50;
    }
    AnotherParentFn.prototype.caller = function()
    {
        var self = this;
        temp();
    }
    ParentFn.prototype.Adding = function()
    {
        var self = this;
        document.getElementById("id_div1").innerHTML = " Method Called and Result of a+b is " + (self.a + self.b);          
    }

</script>
```

In body i use

```
<button onclick="initer()"> Click here to test </button>
<div id="id_div1"></div>
```

Problem is when AnotherParentFn.prototype.caller is called from initer() function temp variable is still undefined. What is wrong with the code??

My task is to assign the function ParentFn.prototype.Adding in a global variable and call the global variable from AnotherParentFn.prototype.caller function. How to achieve it?

Comment: Your temp variable is already global now

Comment: Would be great if you could accept any of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parentheses are used to execute a function.
When you assign the value to `temp`, you are calling the function and assigning the result (`undefined`) to `temp`.  To store a reference to the function in `temp`, omit the parentheses.

```
temp = obj.Adding;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save it as a global variable. It's already saved in `ParentFn.prototype`. All you need to do is invoke it with `.call` and pass in your desired receiver. You can implement `AnotherParentFn.prototype.caller` like this:

```
AnotherParentFn.prototype.caller = function()
{
    ParentFn.prototype.Adding.call(this);
}
```

This way you can get rid of `temp` completely. You also don't need to assign `this` to a local `var self` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

By writing   `temp = obj.Adding();`  it stores the return value. not function pointer in `temp`. Use this

```
function initer()
{
    temp = obj.Adding;
    obj2.caller();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the reference to `obj.Adding` is not assigned properly; it should be this (without parentheses):

```
function initer()
{
    temp = obj.Adding;
    obj2.caller();
}
```

Then, inside `AnotherParentFn.prototype.caller` itself, you must pass the current object as `this` explicitly during the invocation by using [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
AnotherParentFn.prototype.caller = function()
{
    temp.call(this);
}
```